# How to use different ifstream modes in c++?

Tags: c++, flags, ifstream

1. According to the reference, if I use `ifstream infile ( "test.txt" , ifstream::in );`  it will `Allow input operations on the stream.` But what are some of the examples of the "input operations"?
2. Is `ifstream infile ( "test.txt" , ifstream::in | ifstream::binary );` the right syntax to use multiple flags?
3. Will it make a difference if I change `ifstream::` to `iso::` ?

Thank you

Comment: I think you mean ios, not iso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. According to the reference, if I use ifstream infile ( "test.txt" ,
>      ifstream::in ); it will Allow input
>      operations on the stream. But what are
>      some of the examples of the "input
>      operations"?

Reading from a file which would mean everything an input stream can support. See `istream` member functions. Typically, you can do both formatted (using `>>`) and unformatted reads (using `read`). Remember that `ifstream` is a specialization of the `basic_ifstream` template for `char` type. Depending on your needs, say to read UTF-16 encoded file, you may have to use a different specialization (`wifstream`) or even use a special locale (read [this](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/3rd_loc.pdf) to know more about locales).

> 2. Is ifstream infile ( "test.txt" , ifstream::in | ifstream::binary );
>      the right syntax to use multiple
>      flags?

Yes.

> 3. Will it make a difference if I change ifstream:: to iso:: ?

No.

Answer (score 0):

Stream operations are `extraction <<` and `insertion >>`. When you do the following assuming 
`file` is of `fstream` type:

```
file << 5 << 6.5 << "Hello World!"; // insertion of data (output)
file >> x >> y >> str; // exaction of data (input)
```

You could also, deal with the `stream` as a `binary stream`. In that case, it doesn't really look like a "`stream`" of data but that gives you random access to the data. In some cases you can't use the binary mode, especially if your data is not available like a network stream. Insertion and Extraction, are the two main operations on streams.

`ifstream` is created as an `input stream` by default. So, `std::ios::in` is redundant in this case. You are using the flags correctly.

all streams inherit from `ios`. So, the flags are available in both places, you can either retrieve them from `ios` directly or from `fstream`.